# Visual Studio 2012 Native Unit testing - Linker problems

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to create a unit tests for C/C++ with the Microsoft Unit Testing Framework for C++. I'm using visual studio 2012 with SP2. I want to test a project which is compiled as dynamic library, and whose classes are declspec-exported. This project is dependent on a few additional libraries which are outside the solution.
I did the following

1. created a new test project add->new item> test-> C++ unit test class
2. added a reference to the tested project under properties->common Properties->Framework and reference. The same could be done to the additional libraries, as they're not under the same solution.
3. under properties->C/C++/additional include directories, added  the paths the headers of tested library and dependent libraries
4. under properties/Linker/Additional dependencies, added the *.lib names
5. under properties/Linker/Additional library directories, added the paths to the libraries

Still, any usage of the additional libraries in the test project causes "unresolved external".
Can anyone help?